# select TOP (all)

Tags: sql-server

```
declare @t int
set @t = 10
if (o = 'mmm') set @t = -1
select top(@t) * from table
```

What if I want generally it resulted with 10 rows, but rarely all of them.

I know I can do this through "SET ROWCOUNT". But is there some variable number, like -1, that causing TOP to result all elements.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The largest possible value that can be passed to `TOP` is `9223372036854775807` so you could just pass that.

Below I use the binary form for max signed bigint as it is easier to remember as long as you know the basic pattern and that bigint is 8 bytes.

```
declare @t bigint =  case when some_condition then 10 else  0x7fffffffffffffff end;

select top(@t) * 
From table
```

If you dont have an order by clause the top 10 will just be any 10 and optimisation dependant.

If you do have an order by clause to define the top 10 and an index to support it then the plan for the query above should be fine for either possible value.

If you don't have a supporting index and the plan shows a sort you should consider splitting into two queries.

Comment: while not incorrect to me readability is important and I hate seeing large numbers like that in code.

Comment: @JonH - Yes. Shame there's no named constants like `@@BIG_INT_MAX`. It could enhance readability if the actual query is quite lengthy compared to having 2 very similar versions though.

Comment: i think select @t=count(*) from table makes more sense than setting into a large number ??

Comment: @sankaras - Why bother? That would then require two queries. One to get the count then one to get the result.

Comment: @jon 5 years later this has been edited to remove the offending large number.

Comment: declare @t bigint =  case when some_condition then cast(10 as bigint) else  cast(0x7fffffffffffffff as bigint) end;

--this code is error less for sql server

Answer (score 5):

im not sure I understand your question.

But if you sometimes want TOP and other times don't just use if / else construct:

```
if (condition)
  'send TOP
  SELECT TOP 10 Blah FROM...
else
  SELECT blah1, blah2 FROM...
```

Comment: that is copy pasting ... i thought itsnot the best practice

Comment: @dynback.com - No this does not involve best practices, it involves readability, performance, and trace plans.  In this case, other developers will understand your intent.

Comment: @dynback.com SQL is a high level language. Conditional SQL statements basically throw the DRY principle out the window. This shouldn't be looked down on because repetition of statements for conditions in SQL can actually be quite beneficial if executed properly.

Comment: @Matthew - If you really wanted to, you could factor out the copy/pasted query into a view.  Then each branch of the if is a simple `SELECT cols FROM view`

Answer (score 2):

You can use dynamic SQL (but I, personally, try to avoid dynamic SQL), where you create a string of the statement you want to run from conditions or parameters.
There's also some good information here on how to do it without dynamic SQL:

https://web.archive.org/web/20150520123828/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com:80/how-do-i-use-a-variable-in-a-top-clause-in-sql-server.html

Comment: i like rowcount version, but fear of transaction problems

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @top bigint = NULL
declare @top_max_value bigint = 9223372036854775807
if (@top IS NULL) 
begin
set @top = @top_max_value
end

select top(@top) * 
from [YourTableName]
```

Answer (score 1):

a dynamic sql version isn't that's hard to do.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[VariableTopSelect] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @t int

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @sql nvarchar(max)

if (@t=10)
begin
    set @sql='select top (10) * from table'
end
else
begin
    set @sql='select * from  table'
end

exec sp_executesql @sql


END
```

with this sp, if they send 10 to the sp, it'll select the top 10, otherwise it'll select all.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible with a UNION and a parameter

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10
Column1, Column2
FROM Table
WHERE @ShowAllResults = 0
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT 
Column1, Column2
FROM Table
WHERE @ShowAllResults = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I've found is to select the needed columns with all of your    conditions into a temporary table, then do your conditional top:

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE(cols...)

INSERT INTO @TempTable
SELECT blah FROM ...

if (condition)
 SELECT TOP 10 * FROM @tempTable
else
 SELECT * FROM @tempTable
```

This way you follow DRY, get your conditional TOP, and are just as easy to read.

Cheers.

Comment: this is highly inefficient, it is pulling all the data from the database and then throwing away the majority of it. furthermore temporary tables are not efficient if the number of rows gets too large. I would NOT do this in a production system.

Answer (score 1):

I might be too late now, or getting too old
But I solved that by using Top(100)Percent

This goes around all complexities

```
Select Top(100)Percent * from tablename;
```

Comment: If you are in a position to edit the query text and add `Percent` why wouldn't you just remove the `TOP`?

Comment: Agree if the tablename does not have order, in my case I had the 100 as variable, so the TOP was needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the statement "SET ROWCOUNT @recordCount" at the beginning of the result query.The variable "@recordCount" can be any positive integer. It should be 0 to return all records.

that means , "SET ROWCOUNT 0" will return all records and "SET ROWCOUNT 15" will return only the TOP 15 rows of result set.

Drawback can be the Performance hit when dealing with large number of records. Also the SET ROWCOUNT will be effective throughout the scope of execution of the whole query.

Comment: This last point bears emphasis: `SET ROWCOUNT` affects *all* statements, including `INSERT`, `DELETE` and `UPDATE` statements. This behavior is deprecated but still present as of SQL Server 2016. Failure to reset `ROWCOUNT` to 0 can have dire consequences.