# Select top n or * based on condition SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I've a situation to pick rows sometimes all in order or sometimes random pick n rows.

So I was trying to make that in single query like this

```
declare @rand int
set @rand = 0

select top (case @rand when 0 then 1000 else @rand end) * 
from MyQuestion  
where PackageID = 10 
order by sequence
```

It's working fine as in my plan. But if total number of rows greater than 1000 it wont work. Then yea if I specify 10000 that will work in that case. But that's not optimal at all I think. So am looking for a solution where I can fetch all rows without any number specified or simply that should ignore the top part and it will fetch all rows when @rand is 0

**Ordering problem**

Another issue in the same query when it requires random pick.

So I changed the query this way for random pick when @rand has some values in it

```
declare @rand int
set @rand=0

select top (case @rand when 0 then 1000 else @rand end) * 
from MyQuestion  
where PackageID = 10 
order by (case @rand when 0 then sequence else NEWID() end)
```

But it throws an error saying

> Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int

So my scenario is to fetch rows randomly based on @rand variable or complete in the order based on sequence column (ordered).

Comment: Why dont you write two different queries and use your application code to select the appropriate one? It might be simpler.

Comment: Next time please do not edit your question to make it a completely new one with a completely new request in it. My response below was a *complete* answer to the given question; but now that your question has changed, the other answers people have provided are now better and my answer is incomplete--through no fault of my own.

Answer (score 2):

The max value of top that can be specified is 9223372036854775807(max value of bigint) for sql server 2012 onwards and 2147483647(max value of int) for sql server 2008.

So if you modify your queries to

```
declare @rand bigint
set @rand=0
select top  (case @rand when 0 then 9223372036854775807else @rand end) * from MyQuestion  where 
PackageID=10 order by sequence
```

it will give you all rows when parameter  @rand has value 0.

link [select TOP (all)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971206/select-top-all)

**order by issue:**
Here you are trying to sort by value, which is not a valid and giving error as the results can be sorted based on the column name used in the select list or using a nonnegative integer representing the position of the column in the select list.

Follow the link for more details
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188385.aspx

from the above link **order_by_expression:**
Specifies a column or expression on which to sort the query result set. A sort column can be specified as a name or column alias, or a nonnegative integer representing the position of the column in the select list.
Multiple sort columns can be specified. Column names must be unique. The sequence of the sort columns in the ORDER BY clause defines the organization of the sorted result set. That is, the result set is sorted by the first column and then that ordered list is sorted by the second column, and so on.
The column names referenced in the ORDER BY clause must correspond to either a column in the select list or to a column defined in a table specified in the FROM clause without any ambiguities.

Comment: order by can be done based on the name of a column in your table, here you are specifying NEWID(), which is giving the error.

Use suitable column name for ordering

Comment: Dear friend am using newid() for random order

Comment: The logical processing stage for ordering comes after select and the input from one stage is used in next stage.

In your case the newid() value is not present in the select list, so it can not be ordered using it

Also to note that the ordering is done based on column names, not by column values. So you can achieve it by using it in select list then use it with an outer query or cte expression.

Link:  

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms189499.aspx

Comment: Updated answer for order by issue with link

Answer (score 1):

There is no performance penalty for specifying a very large number for the `TOP` clause, even if the number of rows is many fewer. You can simply use the maximum value for the `int` data type, `2147483647`, and go your merry way.

The query engine, as soon as it determines that all inputs are exhausted, will stop producing rows and the query will terminate and return a result.

**UPDATE - the completely changed question**

Since `sequence` is an int column, it's not compatible with the result of `NewID()`, which is a `uniqueidentifier` (GUID). Try this:

```
ORDER BY
   CASE @rand WHEN 0 THEN Sequence ELSE NULL END,
   CASE @rand WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE NewID() END
```

Comment: Thanks boss, If so it clears my worry. But kindly check the Edit I made on the question.

Answer (score 0):

you could use dynamic query if you want like this

```
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @Rand int

set @Rand=0

if(@Rand=0)
BEGIN
    SET @Query='*'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   SET @Query='top '+CAST(@Rand AS NVARCHAR)+' *'
END

SET @Query= 'SELECT '+@Query+' FROM MyQuestion WHERE PackageID=10 ORDER BY sequence' 

exec sp_executesql @Query
```

or you can do this :

```
declare @rand int
set @rand=0
select top  (case @rand when 0 then (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyQuestion) else @rand end) *
from
MyQuestion  where 
PackageID=10 order by sequence
```

As far as your ordering problem is concerned,
you can introduce some random new column with constant value and use it in your order by clause like following query if you don't want order by :

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT *, your_New_Random_column=0
    FROM tbl_Securities
) d
ORDER BY (case @rand  when 0 then ID else your_New_Random_column end) DESC
```

Again, Dynamic query could work as well

Comment: The syntax you've presented in your final code block will not work.