# Select top n query - what can I plug into n to select all?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query:

```
Select top(@val) from myTable
```

In fact, this is in Dapper in an asp.net MVC 5 site - but I assume the principle is the same.

Rather than have an if with one branch selecting all (dropping the top(@val)) - and the other branch selecting the top n records. Is there a value I can pass to @val to just select all - as if the top statement wasn't there? (eg passing in 0 or -1 say - (I tried these, 0 returns 0 rows, -1 returns a syntax error)).

I don't want to just pass an arbitrary high number in as this may cause issues later, is inelegant, and may be less efficient.

Is there a solution here or am I stuck with passing in a high number or doing an if statement?

I can't find anything on Google about this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [select TOP (all)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971206/select-top-all)

Comment: What's wrong with a (very) high number?

Comment: @Shnugo a very high number that seems high enough now may not be later, it may be less efficient than 'top all', and it's inelegant.

Comment: The linked answer shows an easy way to introduce your own logic with `CASE WHEN`. There is no *built-in* value for this...

Comment: *"arbitrary high number [...] may cause issues later"* >> I can't see any. *"inelegant"* >> How so? The query is the same. *"may be less efficient"* >> If the query is trivial, having a branch with `IF` is ok IMO. If it isn't, the very large number is the best option you have AFAICT. You could maybe build the query dynamically but then the query needs to be parsed on each execution.

Comment: my conclusion is I can't do what I want to do in an elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you need but may be this will work for your needs:

```
select top (select count(*) from myTable) * from myTable
```

But I have no idea if you will be able to produce such query from `Dapper`...

Comment: interesting idea - although performance will almost certainly be hit here