# Are there any existing, elegant, patterns for an optional TOP clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Take the (simplified) stored procedure defined here:

```
create procedure get_some_stuffs
  @max_records int = null
as
begin
  set NOCOUNT on

  select top (@max_records) *
  from my_table
  order by mothers_maiden_name
end
```

I want to restrict the number of records selected *only if* `@max_records` is provided.

Problems:

1. The *real* query is nasty and large; I want to avoid having it duplicated similar to this:

   ```
   if(@max_records is null)
   begin
     select *
     from {massive query}
   end
   else
   begin
     select top (@max_records)
     from {massive query}
   end
   ```
2. An arbitrary sentinel value doesn't feel right:

   ```
   select top (ISNULL(@max_records, 2147483647)) *
   from {massive query}
   ```

   For example, if `@max_records` is `null` and `{massive query}` returns less than `2147483647` rows, would this be identical to:

   ```
   select * 
   from {massive query}
   ```

   or is there some kind of penalty for selecting `top (2147483647) *` from a table with only 50 rows?

Are there any other existing patterns that allow for an optionally count-restricted result set without duplicating queries or using sentinel values?

Comment: What is stopping you from setting the default on the parameter to 2147483647?

Comment: you are basically setting a view threshold. why won't you setup a system-wide threshold and then override at the user level?

what i'm saying is.. have a sysmax = 1000 then retrieve usermax ... compare that it should not go over the sysmax... ideally you should not be displaying everything in a view.. specifically all columns

Comment: I think part of your question is tha you want to know if there is an overhead to setting a max value much higher then the actual records. Everything tells me that there shouldn't be. Furthermore, if your tables are indexed properly the overhead (if any) would be negligible.

Comment: Similar question: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/147112/is-there-a-value-that-i-can-use-in-a-select-top-that-will-return-all-rows

Comment: Another similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971206/select-top-all

Comment: Added three examples that I think you will find insightful. Use ISNUMERIC(Column), which is a yes-no answer and much faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was thinking about this, and although I like the explicitness of the `IF` statement in your `Problem 1` statement, I understand the issue of duplication. As such, you could put the main query in a single CTE, and use some trickery to query from it (the **bolded** parts being the highlight of this solution):

```
CREATE PROC get_some_stuffs
(
    @max_records int = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    WITH staged AS (
        -- Only write the main query one time
        SELECT * FROM {massive query}
    )
    -- This part below the main query never changes:
    SELECT * 
    FROM (
        -- A little switcheroo based on the value of @max_records
        SELECT * FROM staged WHERE @max_records IS NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT TOP(ISNULL(@max_records, 0)) * FROM staged WHERE @max_records IS NOT NULL
    ) final
    -- Can't use ORDER BY in combination with a UNION, so move it out here
    ORDER BY mothers_maiden_name
END
```

I looked at the actual query plans for each and the optimizer is smart enough to completely avoid the part of the `UNION ALL` that doesn't need to run.

The `ISNULL(@max_records, 0)` is in there because `TOP NULL` isn't valid, and it will not compile.

Comment: I like this creative approach, albeit with some mild convolution.  I wonder if it affects index selection on subqueries (which I've seen with similar `union all`s)?  Will do some testing and come back - but thanks!

Comment: Yes you can use ORDER BY in combination with a UNION, but this also works, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few methods, but as you probably notice these all look ugly or are unnecessarily complicated. Furthermore, do you really need that ORDER BY?

You could use `TOP (100) PERCENT` and a View, but the PERCENT only works if you do not really need that expensive `ORDER BY`, **since SQL Server will ignore your `ORDER BY` if you try it.**

I suggest taking advantage of stored procedures, but first lets explain the difference in the type of procs:

**Hard Coded Parameter Sniffing**

```
--Note the lack of a real parametrized column. See notes below.
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[USP_TopQuery]', 'U') IS NULL
    EXECUTE('CREATE PROC dbo.USP_TopQuery AS ')
GO
ALTER PROC [dbo].[USP_TopQuery] @MaxRows NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000) = N'SELECT * FROM dbo.ThisFile'
      , @Option NVARCHAR(50) = 'TOP (' + @MaxRows + ') *'
IF ISNUMERIC(@MaxRows) = 0
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL     
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL, '*', @Option)
        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
    END
END
```

**Local Variable Parameter Sniffing**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[USP_TopQuery2]', 'U') IS NULL
    EXECUTE('CREATE PROC dbo.USP_TopQuery2 AS ')
GO
ALTER PROC [dbo].[USP_TopQuery2] @MaxRows INT NULL
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Rows INT;
    SET @Rows = @MaxRows;

IF @MaxRows IS NULL
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.THisFile   
ELSE
    SELECT TOP (@Rows) *
    FROM dbo.THisFile
END
```

**No Parameter Sniffing, old method**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[USP_TopQuery3]', 'U') IS NULL
    EXECUTE('CREATE PROC dbo.USP_TopQuery3 AS ')
GO
ALTER PROC [dbo].[USP_TopQuery3] @MaxRows INT NULL
AS
BEGIN

IF @MaxRows IS NULL
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.THisFile   
ELSE
    SELECT TOP (@MaxRows) *
    FROM dbo.THisFile
END
```

> **PLEASE NOTE ABOUT PARAMETER SNIFFING:**
>
> SQL Server initializes variables in Stored Procs at the *time of compile*, not when it parses.
>
> This means that SQL Server will be unable to guess the query and will
>   choose the **last valid execution plan** for the query, regardless of
>   whether it is even good.

There are two methods, hard coding an local variables that allow the Optimizer to guess.

1. Hard Coding for Parameter Sniffing

   - Use sp_executesql to not only reuse the query, but prevent SQL Injection.
   - However, in this type of query, will not always perform substantially better since a TOP Operator is not a column or table (so the statement effectively has no variables **in this version I used**)
   - Statistics at the time of the creation of your compiled plan will dictate how affective the method is if you are not using a variable on a predicate (`ON`, `WHERE`, `HAVING`)
   - Can use options or hint to `RECOMPILE` to overcome this issue.
2. Variable Parameter Sniffing

   - Variable Paramter sniffing, on the other hand, is flexible enough to work witht the statistics here, and in my own testing it seemed the variable parameter had the advantage of the query using statistics (particularly after I updated the statistics).

[image: Top Queries]

- Ultimately, the issue of performance is about which method will use the least amount of steps to traverse through the leaflets. **Statistics**, the **rows** in your table, and the **rules** for when SQL Server will decide to use a Scan vs Seek impact the performance.
- Running different values will show performances change significantly, though typically better than USP_TopQuery3. So **DO NOT ASSUME** one method is necessarily better than the other.

  - Also note you can use a table-valued function to do the same, but as Dave Pinal would say:

> If you are going to answer that ‘To avoid repeating code, you use
>   Function’ ‑ please think harder! Stored procedure can do the same...
>
> if you are going to answer
>   with ‘Function can be used in SELECT, whereas Stored Procedure cannot
>   be used’ ‑ again think harder!
>
> [SQL SERVER – Question to You – When to use Function and When to use Stored Procedure](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/06/04/sql-server-question-to-you-when-to-use-function-and-when-to-use-stored-procedure/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`SET ROWCOUNT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx):

```
create procedure get_some_stuffs
  @max_records int = null
as
begin
  set NOCOUNT on

  IF @max_records IS NOT NULL
  BEGIN
     SET ROWCOUNT @max_records
  END

  select top (@max_records) *
  from my_table
  order by mothers_maiden_name

  SET ROWCOUNT 0

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this (using your example):

```
create procedure get_some_stuffs
  @max_records int = null
as
begin
  set NOCOUNT on

  select top (ISNULL(@max_records,1000)) *
  from my_table
  order by mothers_maiden_name
end
```

I know you don't like this (according to your point 2), but that's pretty much how it's done (in my experience).

Comment: @Alex, it doesn't.  I'm just telling you not to worry about doing it this way.

Comment: Okay thanks.  I was really hoping there was something better.

Comment: Someone smarter than me may come along with a brilliant option... and we'll both learn something.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this (you're have to really look at execution plans and I didn't have time to set anything up)?

```
create procedure get_some_stuffs
  @max_records int = null
as
begin
  set NOCOUNT on

  select *, ROW_NUMBER(OVER order by mothers_maiden_name) AS row_num
  from {massive query}
  WHERE @max_records IS NULL OR row_num < @max_records
end
```

Another thing you can do with {massive query} is make a view or inline table-valued function (it it's parametrized), which is generally a pretty good practice for anything big and repetitively used.